# Extract UoM text between two round brackets only after a specific string

Tags: sql, regex, exasol

I have a large string in the form of

`Anschlüsse/Schnittstellen=(USB 3.0)|Bildschirmgröße=59,9 cm (23,6 Zoll)|Bluetooth=Bluetooth 4.0|`

I need to extract `23,6` out of `Bildschirmgröße=59,9 cm (23,6 Zoll)|`

I tried

```
/(?<=Bildschirmgröße=)(?:.+?\()(.*?)(?:\))(?=\|)
```

but that returns 2 matches

```
59,9 cm (23,6 Zoll)
23,6 Zoll
```

and in my SQL query I only get the first result instead of the second.

Trying to only get the correct match via

```
(?<=Bildschirmgröße=)(?:.+?\()(\(.*?\))(?:\))(?=\|)
```

returns nothing/NULL?

Comment: Try `Bildschirmgröße=[^(]*\(\K.*?(?=\)\|)` or `Bildschirmgröße=[^(]*\(\K[^()]+`

Comment: Thanks, that works! What would I need to change if I just wanted to get `23,6`?

Comment: I added an answer explaining that. UoM extraction is a common task, but extracting these values in specific lexical context is not so evident, so there can be multiple solutions depending on languages and their locales you need to cover. I tried to provide a template solution for that, you may want to further adjust it (say, support `.` as a decimal separator, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know UoM extraction as its own term is a thing.

Comment: Units of measurement (UoMs) has been a pain in the neck for all translation companies, and now MT has a problem with them, too, so having tools to identify them is going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is not actually two matches, you get the whole match value and the Group 1 value.

In order to get just the UoM value, you can use the following PCRE compliant pattern (since [Exasol uses PCRE](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/regexp_substr.htm) behind its regex functions):

```
Bildschirmgröße=[^(]*\(\K[^()]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DtllXm/1).

To only get the number, you can use

```
Bildschirmgröße=[^(]*\(\K\d+(?:,\d+)?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DtllXm/2).

*Details*:

- `Bildschirmgröße=` - a literal text
- `[^(]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `[^()]+` - one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of `,` and one or more digits. Note you may use a more lenient and at the same time more universal extraction pattern for UoM like `\d[\d,.]*\s+\w+` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DtllXm/3)).